# How to write these queries in Mongo shell?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Suppose I've got a collection of documents like that:

```
  {
      "postId" : "12345",
      "blogId" : "xyz",
      "title"  : "My blog post",
      ...
      "tags"   : ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
  }
```

I've got also an index on "blogId" and "tags".

Now I need to write two queries/aggregates in mongo shell:

- `query1` to count all distinct "tags" of all items with the same "blogId".
- `query2` to count items with the same "blogId" for each "tags"

Suppose, for example, that the collection contains two items with `"blogId = "xyz"` :

```
  {
      "postId" : "12345",
      "blogId" : "xyz",
      "title"  : "My blog post 1",
      ...
      "tags"   : ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
  }, 
  {
      "postId" : "67890",
      "blogId" : "xyz",
      "title"  : "My blog post 2",
      ...
      "tags"   : ["tag1", "tag3", "tag4"]
  }
```

In this case I expect the queries to work like that:

- `query1` returns `["tag1", "tag2", "tag3", "tag4"]`
- `query2` returns `["tag1" : 2, "tag2" : 1, "tag3" : 2. "tag4" : 1 ]`

How would suggest me write these queries ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to write two queries for this, just a single pipeline with multiple stages that shape the two results you want.

In your pipeline, you need the first step as the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) pipeline stage which will filter the documents in the collection on the specified field:

```
db.getCollection('blogs').aggregate([
    { "$match": { "blogId": "xyz" } }
])
```

The next stage in the pipeline will be to flatten the tags array with [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) so they can be grouped later:

```
db.getCollection('blogs').aggregate([
    { "$match": { "blogId": "xyz" } },
    { "$unwind": "$tags" }
])
```

Once you get the denormalised documents you can then [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) them to get the counts:

```
db.getCollection('blogs').aggregate([
    { "$match": { "blogId": "xyz" } },
    { "$unwind": "$tags" },
    { "$group": {
         "_id": "$tags",
         "count": { "$sum": 1 },
    } }
])
```

The result from the above pipeline can be piped again into another [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage to shape get the distinct tags:

```
db.getCollection('blogs').aggregate([
    { "$match": { "blogId": "xyz" } },
    { "$unwind": "$tags" },
    { "$group": {
         "_id": "$tags",
         "count": { "$sum": 1 },
    } },
    { "$group": {
         "_id": null,
         "query1": { "$push": "$_id" },
         "query2": { "$push": { "k": "$_id", "v": "$count" } }
    } }
])
```

On getting the distinct tags and their counts contained in a list, you can then project the field to a desired format which is a hash of the tags and their counts, using [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) as:

```
db.getCollection('blogs').aggregate([
    { "$match": { "blogId": "xyz" } },
    { "$unwind": "$tags" },
    { "$group": {
         "_id": "$tags",
         "count": { "$sum": 1 },
    } },
    { "$group": {
         "_id": null,
         "query1": { "$push": "$_id" },
         "query2": { "$push": { "k": "$_id", "v": "$count" } }
    } },
    { "$addFields": {
       "query2": { "$arrayToObject": "$query2" } 
    } }
])
```

The output from the above example is

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "query1" : [ 
        "tag1", 
        "tag3", 
        "tag2", 
        "tag4"
    ],
    "query2" : {
        "tag4" : 1,
        "tag2" : 1,
        "tag3" : 2,
        "tag1" : 2
    }
}
```

For aggregating all the documents you would need to remove the first [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) pipeline stage but this will incur a huge performance penalty should your collection be large as [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) produces a copy of each document per array element and that uses more memory possible memory cap on aggregation pipelines of 10% total memory, thus takes time to flatten the arrays as well as processing. So be mindful of starting your pipeline with an [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stage.